# Is it possible to get the current date of an HTTP Live Stream being played through AirPlay?

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, http-live-streaming, airplay

Working on an **iOS** project that uses **HTTP Live Streaming** (HLS), we found that when the app uses AirPlay, to play the streaming on a Apple TV, the `currentDate` property of the `currentItem` of the AVPlayer returns `nil`. In other words:

```
AVPlayerItem *item = [player currentItem]; //Where "player" is the AVPlayer object.
NSDate *date = [item currentDate]; //date is nil, when using AirPlay.
```

So, is it possible to get that currentDate by other means?

Answer (score 0):

You should include `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` tag info in your m3u8 files. 
For example, if I created a live stream at 2017/7/12 12:00:00

I should add

`#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2017-07-12T12:00:00.000Z` in my .m3u8 header

and you will get currentDate when you call the method in playerItem.(However, that date info is only supported to `s` not `ms` unit.)